# Java: Replacing Special Characteres on .ics file (ICAL)?

Tags: java, icalendar

I'm using ical4j to parse an ics file, but it seems the ical file have special characters like (á,é, í,ó,ú and ñ) and appears as "?".

I want to replace all these characters in java, it's posible?

Answer (score 0):

ical by default uses UTF-8 encoding. You are seeing ? (presumably in a terminal?) because the encoding of your terminal is not UTF-8.

Fix the terminal encoding and you won't need to remove the special characters.

You don't mention your OS. In Unixes you'd look at the LC_* environment variables.

Comment: I'm using Linux (Fedora) .

But when i open the file on gedit, leafpad or another text editor the special characters appears like (?, ¢)

And java just shows ?

Comment: what exactly do you mean 'java just shows ?'. To see what value java has you must be printing it to a terminal or viewing it in a debugger? In either case the encoding of whatever is displaying the value is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with character encoding.